# Java/OpenAPI - Cannot generate Model class for array of objects

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

Description
I am trying to expose an internal API for customers to use. For this; I am generating the Swagger api-docs from the API response, and generating the YAML file with it.

Then to the YAML file I am using 'openapi-generator-maven-plugin' to create the model files that will point to internal code for the external users to view the response.

openapi-generator version
spring-boot: 2.3.2.RELEASE
Java: 1.8
okhttp: 4.8.1
gson: 2.8.6
openapitools: 4.3.1
code-findbugs: 3.0.2

OpenAPI declaration file content or url
I have in response:

```
{
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 200,
  "total": 136,
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success"
  },
  "count": 136,
  "reponseLastModified": "2020-09-02T20:56:57.951+0000",
  "adjustments": [
    {
      "name1": "value1",
      "name2": value2,
      "name3": value3,
      "name4": "value4"
    },
   {
      "name1": "value1",
      "name2": value2,
      "name3": value3,
      "name4": "value4"
    }
  ]
}
```

For the above, I generated the Swagger JSON and converted to YAML code(removing some parts):

```
responses:
          200:
            description: OK
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/AdjustmentResponse'
     AdjustmentResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        offset:
          type: integer
          description: 'The number of items to offset the start of the list from.'
          format: int32
          example: 5
        limit:
          type: integer
          description: 'The number of items you want the list to be limited to.'
          format: int32
          example: 10
        total:
          type: integer
          description: 'The total number of items that are in the entire collection.'
          format: int32
          example: 50
        count:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        reponseLastModified:
          type: string
        adjustments:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Adjustment'
    Adjustment:
      type: object
      properties:
        name1:
          type: string
          description: 'ABCD'
        name2:
          type: integer
          description: 'ABCD'
          example: 39
        name3:
          type: string
          description: 'ABCD'
        name4:
          type: integer
          description: 'ABCD'
          example: 39
```

Generation Details
As above

Steps to reproduce
When I generate the Models, it will generate the models but will not generate the response API from what I generated the Swagger.

Changing the YAML file to below will generate the response but then the model file 'Adjustment' does not get generated since in AdjustmentResponse DTO it shows up as: List adjustments.

```
....
adjustments:
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Adjustment'
    Adjustment:
      type: array
.....
```

Comment: Your schema definition is correct. This looks like a bug in the generator. Open an issue here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues